# Problem to setState with array, losing the first position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that receives an array via props. I need to save this array in the state of component, so my component looks like this:

```
...
const [mediaIds, setMediaIds] = useState();
...

function mediaChange (mediaArray){
    console.log(mediaArray);
    setMediaIds(mediaArray);
    console.log(mediaIds);
}
```

In the first console.log I print the array that arrives via props, in the second I print the State already changed.

The problem is that it seems that it skips the first position of the array, below I will show my console.log. The first being the mediaArray and the second the mediaIds:

```
[2, 3]
[2]

[2, 3, 7]
[2, 3]

[2, 3, 7, 4]
[2, 3, 7]


[2, 3, 7, 4, 6]
[2, 3, 7, 4]


[2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]
[2, 3, 7, 4, 6]

[2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 1]
[2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]

[2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 1, 8]
[2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal repository reproducing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`useState` is not synchronous for many reasons. Use the `useEffect` function if you want to do something when the new value has been assigned.

Read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

create a state variable (useState and all) that you will update, whenever you want to change whatever data array you want to change. then put this state variable in the dependencies array of the useEffect hook, then make whatever change to the data array accordingly (differences in changing an array vs changing an object) in the function you pass to the useEffect(functionToMakeChange(),[dependecy variable]).